# Magento Category Layout - Spliting catalog/category/view.pthml

Tags: magento, layout, categories

Magento 1.7.0.2

I have Easy Catalogue Images installed by Templates Master. I would like to have the title, RSS Link, description etc. appear above this module and the products listed below.

I have therefore split view.phtml into title.ptmhl and view.phtml and would like the following layout.

title.phtml

Easy Catalogue image

view.phtml

My title.phtml is located at catalog/category/title.phtml as follows:

```
<?php
$_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$categoryName = $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName());
$_imgHtml   = '';
if ($_imageUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
    $_imgHtml = '<img src="'.$_imageUrl.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" />';
    $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
}?>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
    <div class="page-title category-title">
<?php if($this->IsRssCatalogEnable() && $this->IsTopCategory()): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getRssLink() ?>" class="link-feed right" title="<?php echo sprintf($this->__('Subscribe to the %s RSS Feed'), $categoryName) ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo sprintf($this->__('Subscribe to %s RSS Feed'), $categoryName) ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<h2><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()), 'name') ?></h2>
</div>

<?php if($_imgHtml): ?>
    <p><?php echo $_imgHtml?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($_description=$_category->getDescription()): ?>
    <p class="category-description std"><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

view.phtml has been altered to exclude all instances of class 'page-title category-title' as above.

I have tried referencing title.phtml in catalog.xml as follows

```
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_title" name="category.title" template="catalog/category/title.phtml">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
```

title.phtml does not show.

Comment: No need to thank here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Can get title.phtml to output when using the following
               <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category_header" before="-" template="catalog/category/title.phtml" />

However this messes up the layout. Is the only way to get this to show properly is to create a new module??